# Swift Development Updating Objects Across Views

Tags: swiftui

I am working on an application and am having issues seeing updates.

I have the following code

```
`struct HomeView {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var userResults: FetchedResults<User>

    var body {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isAuthenticated) {
                if let user = UserService.getUserByUsername(username) {
                    UserDetailView(user: user)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

`struct UserDetailView {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var bookCollectionResults: FetchedResults<Collection>
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        _bookCollectionResults = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: 
            BookCollectionService.getBookCollectionsByUser(user: user))
    }

    var body {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Lists")) {
                ListView(bookCollections: bookCollectionResults)
            }
        }
    }
}`

`struct ListView {
    let bookCollections: FetchedResults<Collection>

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(bookCollections) { bookCollection in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ListDetailView(bookCollection: bookCollection)
                    .navigationTitle(bookCollection.name)
            ) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        ListCellView(bookCollection: bookCollection)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

`struct ListDetailView {
    let bookCollection: Collection
    @State private var openEdit: Bool = false

    init(bookCollection: Collection) {
        self.bookCollection = bookCollection
        _bookResults = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: 
            BookService.getBooksByBookCollection(bookCollection: bookCollection))
    }

    var body {
        List {
            Section () {
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $openEdit) {
                NavigationView {
                    EditListView(bookCollection: bookCollection) { name, description in
                        do {
                            try BookCollectionService.saveBookCollectionChanges(name: name, description: description, for: bookCollection)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    openEdit = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

`struct EditListView {
    let bookCollection: Collection

    let onSave: (String, String?) -> Void

    init(bookCollection: Collection, onSave: @escaping (String, String?) -> Void) {
        self.bookCollection = bookCollection
        self._name = State(initialValue: bookCollection.name)
        self._description = State(initialValue: bookCollection.collectionDescription ?? "")
        self.onSave = onSave
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                TextField("Description", text: $description)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("Add Description")
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button("Close") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Done") {
                    onSave(name, description)
                    
                    dismiss()
                }
                .disabled(!isFormValid)
            }
            
        }
    }
}`
```

When I am on the EditListView and I update the list name I am able to see the changes in EditListView, but when I navigate back to UserDetailView the updated list name does not appear. To get the updated list name to appear I have to navigate back to UsersView and then click on the user again to see the UserDetailView.

Comment: All CoreData objects are ObservableObjects they should be wrapped with @ObservedObject at every level to see changes

Comment: @loremipsum So should I make the main variable in each view @ObservedObject?

Comment: Each bookCollection and userResult (core data objects), at every level

Comment: Please show us `ListViewCell`, I bet it is missing `@ObservedObject`

Comment: Btw initing property wrappers in a `View` init like that is a bad idea, you'll run into consistency issues. There are better ways to update fetch request predicates and create scratch pad core data objects for editing.